# Who makes the super hero costumes?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, costume

All superheroes have nice costumes. Who makes them? Many of them have secret identities to protect. How can these costumes be created without them losing their secret identities? Do they make their own costumes? Do they hire someone?

Comment: I assume like the NFL, they signed a contract with Nike.

Comment: @zog Do you have any particular superheroes within the Marvel Cinematic Universe in mind? Most of the ones we have seen so far do not actively maintain secret identities, as explained in my question/answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100804/does-the-general-public-know-who-superheroes-really-are-in-the-marvel-cinematic).

Comment: [*Edna Mode* obviously...](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/e/e5/Edna_Mode.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150215210228)

Comment: it depends on the movie.

Comment: Spider-Man and Deadpool make their own costumes, this is also shown in the movies.

Comment: This almost certainly seems waaay too broad for a reasonable answer, if even on-topic.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Obviously not, Thor and Vision have capes. And you know what Edna thinks of those.

Comment: I realise that I answered this question, but I have chosen to VTC as "too broad" because the already lengthy list I have wrote is only going to get longer in the future.

Answer (score 30):

This is tagged with the [marvel-cinematic-universe](/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) tag, so I'm going to answer from that perspective.

In roughly the order we were introduced to them;

### Films

- **Tony Stark, AKA Iron Man**. He created his first Iron Man suit when in captivity in Afghanistan. Since then, he has upgraded and tweaked the suit many, many times.
- **Bruce Banner, AKA The Hulk**. He has no costume.
- **Natasha Romanoff, AKA Black Widow**. Her costume would have been provided by SHIELD, her employer throughout most films she appears in so far.
- **James 'Rhodey' Rhodes, AKA War Machine.** His costume was designed by Tony Stark before being stolen and further modified by the US Army.
- **Thor Odinson.** Although what he wears may looks strange to us, it is actually just standard Asgardian armour, possibly somewhat fancier than usual thanks to his status as Prince of Asgard.
- **Clint Barton, AKA Hawkeye.** Like Natasha Romanoff, his suit and equipment would have been provided by SHIELD.
- **Steve Rogers, AKA Captain America.** His first costume was designed for him as part of a propaganda campaign, before being upgraded by Howard Stark in order for him to take an active role in the Second World War. Since then, he has had a costume designed by SHIELD Agent Phil Coulson, before being employed by SHIELD and later joining The Avengers full time.
- **James Buchanan 'Bucky' Barnes, AKA The Winter Soldier**. Other than the standard military style gear he wears, his equipment and robotic arm were created by Hydra.
- **Sam Wilson, AKA The Falcon**. His costume is the EXO-7 Falcon, a piece of military equipment that he stole. Later changes to it (such as colour, style) were done when he became an Avengers.
- **Pietro Maximoff, AKA Quicksilver**. We never really see Pietro in anything that could be described as a costume.
- **Wanda Maximoff, AKA The Scarlet Witch**. We have not yet seen Wanda in anything that could be described as a costume.
- **The Vision.** He looks pretty weird by default, but we do see him create a cape for himself based on the one that Thor wears.
- **Scott Lang, AKA Ant-Man**. His costume was created by Hank Pym, a scientist who previously used the Ant-Man suit to fight for SHIELD some decades ago.
- **Hope van Dyne, AKA The Wasp**. Although we haven't seen her use it yet, her costume was created by Hank Pym and his wife, and has now been handed down to her.
- **T'Challa, AKA Black Panther**. The title of Black Panther is passed down over generations, which might mean the costume is too. Regardless, it's infused with vibranium and was created in his homeland of Wakanda.

---

### Agents of SHIELD

- **Mike Peterson, AKA Deathlok.** His "costume" is a series of cybernetic enhancements created by Cybertek in association with Hydra.
- **Daisy Johnson, AKA Skye, AKA Tremors**. Her gauntlets were designed by Agent Jemma Simmons. Presumably, her suit was also provided by SHIELD after she set up her Secret Warriors team.
- **Lincoln Campbell, AKA Sparkplug**. Like Daisy, his suit will have been created and provided by SHIELD when he joined the Secret Warriors.
- **Joey Gutierrez**. As a member of Secret Warriors, he too was given a suit by SHIELD.

---

### Netflix shows

- **Matthew Murdock, AKA Daredevil**. His costume was created by Melvin Potter, a tailor who creates special protective suits for Wilson Fisk and his associates.
- **Jessica Jones**. She did have a costume that was created by her friend Trish Walker, but as far as we know her career as a superhero was both short lived and didn't actually include her wearing the costume.
- **Luke Cage**. So far in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, we have not seen him wear anything that could be described as a superhero costume.
- **Elektra Natchios**. Her "costume" appears to simply be a strange combination of ordinary clothes that allow her to hide her face, as well as giving her the flexibility required to fight.
- **Frank Castle, AKA The Punisher**. No costume of sorts, simply a black jacket and body armour.

Comment: Jessica Jones never was Jewel in the MCU so she never wore the costume and never "gave up" being a super hero as she never was one.  The costume and the name "Jewel" were easter eggs for fans of the comics, and Trish having some fun at Jessica's expense.

Comment: MCU doesn't include X-Men? That whole thing is so confusing.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: For a long time, Marvel gave off rights for cinematographics right, and still haven t retrieved them all. Fox have the right on Fantastic 4 and X Men (including any mention of mutants), Sony have the rights on Spiderman.

Comment: *"The Hulk. He has no costume."* So those magically stretchy pants don't count? ;)

Comment: maybe Rhodey _isn't_ a superhero...